# Como ocultar uma linha de tabela que a informação contenha *

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho uma tabela que quando o não se tem informação ela fica preenchida com um `*` por exemplo:

```
<tr>
   <td>Quant. do produto</td>
   <td>*</td>
</tr>
```

Mas a mesma pode aparecer com informação:

```
<tr>
   <td>Quant. do produto</td>
   <td>12</td>
</tr>
```

Como eu faria para ocultar a que tá sem informação (possuindo o `*`) dinamicamente?

Obs: se caso necessário, posso remover o `*` e deixar simplesmente vazio .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que usando JQuery seria mais prático assim:

```js
$('tr:has(td:contains("*"))').hide();
```

Comment: Mais aí vc não está escondendo a linha, apenas a célula.

Comment: Faz sentido sua observação, fiz um ajuste para pegar pelo <tr>

Answer (score 4):

Basta percorrer todas as `td`'s e remover a linha da `td` que tiver apenas o asterisco:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
   // seleciona todas as td's da tabela
   var tab = document.querySelectorAll("table td");
   for(var x=0; x<tab.length; x++){
      var td = tab[x];
      if(td.textContent.trim() == "*"){
         // remove a linha
         td.parentNode.outerHTML = '';
      }
   }
});
```

```html
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>Quant. do produto</td>
      <td>*</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Quant. do produto</td>
      <td>12</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Quant. do produto</td>
      <td>*</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Tem como fazer isso acontecer automaticamente?

Comment: Tem sim. Alterei a resposta. ;)

Comment: Vlw pela ajuda amigo ;)